# React Native: GIF is not animated

Tags: android, react-native, gif

This is my **Modal component**:

```
    export default function LoadingModal(props) {
      const {visible} = props;
      return (
        <Modal transparent visible={visible}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Image
              style={styles.loadingGif}
              source={require('../../asset/images/loading.gif')}
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
```

Everything is working except the **GIF** is not animated.

I follow [React native components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android) for RN 0.65 and add

```
    // For animated GIF support
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

into **android/app/build.gradle** at `dependencies` section but it's still not working,

```
    cd android
    ./gradlew clean
    cd ..
    react-native run-android ( yarn android )
```

is not working, too.

I have no idea about it. So I wish that anyone can help me with this problem.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed**

Just use `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'`

Answer (score 1):

**Working for RN 0.71.**

Add to `android/app/build.gradle` into `dependencies` following line: `implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0")`